# Test the difference between average value of 2 random variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, f-test, marketing

I am doing an exercise on marketing analysis to determine the strategy that a brand should follow based on historical weekly data collected from supermarkets that sell the brand (let say brand1) and 4 other competitors' products (brand2, 3, 4 and 5 respectively). The weekly data contains sales, average price ... of each brand by period, week and store number.

I want to analyse that whether brand 3 is doing better than our brand (brand 1) on average weekly sales. I am thinking about the two sample student's t-test. $H_0$ would be $\mu_3 - \mu_1 \ge 0$ and $H_1$ would be $\mu_3 - \mu_1 < 0$. ($\mu_3, \mu_1$ are the mean of weekly sales of brand 3 and brand 1 respectively).

Firstly, using a Fisher’s F-test to verify the homogeneity of variances. If the p-value is less than the significance level or if the F-value is less than the tabulated F-value, then we accept the null hypothesis of homogeneity of variances.

Secondly, implement the t-test for homogeneous variances. But I don't know what to do in case the null hypothesis $H_0$ is  $\mu_3 - \mu_1 \ge 0$ (instead of $\mu_3 - \mu_1 = 0$).

Could anyone please help me on this case? Is there any other test more suitable to perform on this problem and if two sample t-test is applicable for the situation, what I need to do since the null hypothesis is $\mu_3 - \mu_1 \ge 0$ ?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Unless you have clear evidence data are not normal, you should use a Welch (separate-variances) t test. Testing for equal variances and then branching to a pooled t test (if equality of variances not rejected) or the Welch test (if rejected) is a deprecated practice. Unless sample sizes are very low, any loss of power using the Welch test will be negligible, even if population variances are in fact identical. // If data are far from normal, then choose a nonparametric alternative to the Welch test.

Comment: @Bruce Why would the criterion be "clear evidence of non-normality"? For one thing, such evidence would often only be *clear* in relatively large samples, but the effects of it could be substantial in small samples.

Comment: I agree "far from normal" is fuzzy, but didn't intend it as quantitative technical terminology. For small samples, I guess the usual phrase to advise against t tests is "extreme skewness or several far outliers", but that's also vague and formal tests are unhelpful for really small samples. For large samples, the t test is remarkably robust against non-normality. Do you know a reliable rule for when to use nonparametric tests on large samples?

Comment: ... Many times I've used t-statistic as metric in a permutation test when a moderately large dataset (say, $n=30$ to $100$) seemed "clearly nonnormal" only to find that the permutation distribution was close to t -- especially in the tails to find P-values.

Comment: @Glen_b and BruceET Thank you for sharing your insights!! I would want to find a textbook that clearly describes the tests and their respective strengths and limitations. Do you have any recommendation for that? Thanks so much again!!

Comment: @Bruce Sorry, for some reason I missed your replies before. I'd try to avoid a criterion that involved looking at the data to choose between tests, since that will impact the properties of the tests you're choosing between. The assumptions would still need to be addressed in some fashion, certainly; though there are ways to do that without necessarily using the same data as you're testing. Where there was no good reason to make an assumption (at least as a reasonable approximation), I'd try to avoid it, either by taking a different parametric assumption,. ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  by robustifying the test against that assumption or by employing a test that was not based on a parametric assumption. Both the impact on significance level and power are important. You're correct that in many cases the permutation distribution of a t- may be close to having a t-distribution, but that on its own won't tell you a lot about the power.